# ReactJS + Docker-Compose ERROR | "Could not find a required file"

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have a ReactJS application which has been dockerized. The application is built into a docker image and run on a container for development also using docker-compose tool. This works well when I use it with Docker for Windows. Below is the package.json, it is a very old reactjs scaffolding.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "react-listbox":"^1.2.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

Folder Structure of the Client Code (Approximate Idea) -

```
client
  -- public
    - index.html
  -- src
    - App.js
  package.json
```

Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  client:
      build:
        context: ./services/client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - './services/client:/usr/src/app' #(map)  outside: inside the docker 
        - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
      ports:
        - 3007:3000
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
```

But when I try to push this docker image to a repository and then use it to deploy into a cloud container (possibly, a unix based system), the deployment fails with NPM ERR (as described below).

STDERR

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-11T03_53_28_432Z-debug.log
```

STDOUT

```
> client@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /usr/src/app/public
```

It fails saying the `index.html` is not found when I am quite sure, the file is under `/public/` which gets mounted to the dockerized image.

`NOTE - I know the fact that this is not the way the reactjs code should be deployed on server. It should be through a web server like nginx. But the legacy team had little knowledge about the front end development. Please help regardless.`

Comment: Probably you are missing the `COPY` step in docker file. Can you post the contents of `Dockerfile`? Are you copying the public folder to docker image?

Comment: @MjZac On your suggestion, I have added the Dockerfile and docker compose config in the question description. Does the public folder need to be copied specifically to the docker image?

Comment: yes, both `public` folder and `src` needs to be copied to the docker image.

Comment: As per your suggestion @MjZac I implemented the changes, but it cropped up a new issue, please find the logs in the comment below your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are mounting `client` folder as a volume in the docker image. So, where ever you deploy the docker image, it will expect the volume to be mounted. Instead, you can copy the folder to docker image and make it self contained.

```
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY public /usr/src/app/public
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install

# start app

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

your `docker-compose-dev.yml` will be:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  client:
      build:
        context: ./services/client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - 3007:3000
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
```

Comment: The issue that is mentioned in the description is not seen anymore, but another issue has cropped up. Please find the logs in the description.

Comment: The logs after your suggestion -

`> client@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: 10.248.40.124
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
Learn more here: CRA-advanced-config

Could not find an open port at 10.248.40.124.
Network error message: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 10.248.40.124`

Comment: That seems like another issue. possible solution is replacing `HOST` environment variable to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. https://medium.com/@choy/fixing-create-react-app-when-npm-fails-to-start-because-your-host-environment-variable-is-being-4c8a9fa0b461

Comment: The solution thereafter still did not solve the next issue. The changes in the docker files did move the logs further. We can keep this question open while I keep trying to fix the issue. Thank you for the help.